# Why does node selection not work properly after TreeModel reload?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode, defaulttreemodel

I have a Swing application that uses a `JTree`. I want some of the nodes of the tree to be hidden, so I have implemented two `DefaultTreeModel`s, one with every node and a filtered one with only the ones that should be displayed. The latter is set as the actual model.

At some points I must change the filtered nodes, and when I do, the items in the tree update properly, but their behavior is wrong. **Nodes do not get highlighted when they are selected (even though they are indeed selected) and the user can no longer double-click to expand a node**, they must click the little '+' button.

Below is a generalization of my code, two methods from my custom class that extends `JTree`.

`updateFilter` gets called when the filter needs to be updated.
`populateFilteredNode` recursively populates the root node of my filtered model. For simplicity, `filteredRoot` is a class member variable (of type `DefaultMutableTreeNode`) and is the root of the filtered model. `fullModel` and `filteredModel` are of type `DefaultTreeModel`

```
public void updateFilter() {
    // Get current expansion state
    ArrayList<Integer> expansionState = getExpansionState();

    DefaultMutableTreeNode fullModelRoot = fullModel.getRoot();

    // Remove existing nodes in the filtered model
    while(filteredRoot.getChildCount() > 0) {
        filteredModel.removeNodeFromParent(filteredRoot.getFirstChild());
    }

    populateFilteredNode(fullModelRoot, filteredRoot);

    // Repaint tree and restore expansion state
    repaint();
    setExpansionState(expansionState);
}

private void populateFilteredNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode fullNode, DefaultMutableTreeNode filteredNode) {

    int index = 0;

    for(int n = 0; n < fullNode.getChildCount(); n++) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode fullChildNode = fullNode.getChildAt(n);

        // Show the item and its children if one of many cases is true
        if(shouldShowItem(fullChildNode.getItem())) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode filteredChildNode = fullChildNode.clone();

            filteredModel.insertNodeInto(filteredChildNode, filteredNode, index++);

            populateFilteredNode(fullChildNode, filteredChildNode);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a similar experience or knows why the selected node will not appear highlighted, please let me know. Or if there is a better way to accomplish filtering. Or if more code would help provide an answer.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"..my custom class that extends `JTree`."* I'd give odds of 100 to 1 that this is **not** a case for extending `JTree`.

Comment: @Andrew I admit I am new to this, so I don't know exactly when I should or shouldn't create a custom subclass. Why would you bet that this is not a case to extend `JTree`? And would that be related to why the selected nodes don't highlight?

Comment: I'll know more when I look at the code. I'll look at the code after there is an MCVE/SSCCE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works for my case, although it's quick and dirty and I don't necessarily understand why it works. [This 12-year-old post](https://coderanch.com/t/339425/java/JTree-won-show-expanded-node) on Code Ranch somehow got me headed in the right direction. I'm just posting it here in case anyone has a similar problem and it might be of help.

I save the selection path before making any changes to the table model, and then call this new function `findNewSelectionPath` after the changes were made. Below is a generalized version of the function (I use several custom classes so I did my best to make it look generically usable).

```
private TreePath findNewSelectionPath(TreePath oldSelectionPath) {
    TreePath newSelectionPath = null;

    if(oldSelectionPath != null) {
        Object[] oldPathComponents = oldSelectionPath.getPath();
        Object[] newPathComponents = new Object[oldPathComponents.length];

        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) filteredModel.getRoot();

        // Set the root
        if(oldPathComponents[0].equals(node)) {
            newPathComponents[0] = node;
        }

        // Set the rest of the path components
        for(int n = 1; n < oldPathComponents.length; n++) {
            for(int k = 0; k < node.getChildCount(); k++) {
                if(oldPathComponents[n].equals(node.getChildAt(k))) {
                    newPathComponents[n] = node.getChildAt(k);
                    node = node.getChildAt(k);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Make sure that the last path component exists
        if(newPathComponents[newPathComponents.length - 1] != null) {
            newSelectionPath = new TreePath(newPathComponents);
        }
    }
    return newSelectionPath;
}
```